# "I texted you on...", "in...", or "by..." – which preposition do I use?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english, sentence-choice

Which of these prepositions is correct in these sentences?

> I texted you **on** WhatsApp.
>   I texted you **in** WhatsApp.
>   I texted you **by** WhatsApp.

Comment: In network communication activity of some kind (such as "on the phone" or "on the internet", generally use *on*.

Answer (score 3):

Of your sentences, this is the most natural:

> I texted you **on** WhatsApp.

However, I think most people would say something different. Your sentence isn't wrong, it just isn't what I would expect to be said. I imagine that most people would use some variation of:

> I **messaged** you **on** WhatsApp.
>   I **messaged** you **through** WhatsApp.

They may also elect to use a different structure:

> I sent you a message on WhatsApp.
>   I sent you a message through WhatsApp.

Generally, *texting* will only be used to refer to the [Short Message Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service), whether that's over traditional telephone networks or through an Internet telephony arrangement. Services that aren't provided by a [network operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_network_operator) – such as WhatsApp, Messenger, IRC, email, and so on – tend to have *to message* as their verb, in my experience.

Comment: I agree with the choice of the preposition, but I think the sense of *text* has changed quite a bit lately. For example, here's a line from *Jurassic World* (2015): *"Call me every day. And text me pics so I don't forget what you look like."* I don't think she meant SMS.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: It could also refer to the [Multimedia Message Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service). MMS messages are often displayed alongside SMS messages on phones.

Comment: WOW, what a big answers I got here! Thanks all of you! 

I have seen texted in the context of SMS and whatsapp, I mean, is that something weird for English people? For example in the game, Life is Strange there is a moment when they say something like texted. In fact, what @LMS says about **messaged** is right because I have seen it on Facebook chat.